# How best to Implement Linked Variables?

Tags: python, geometry

I am implementing a geometry solver program, which will try to solve for all the other measurements in the figure with the data that is given (see image link)

In such a figure, the lengths or measurements of the shapes are implicitly linked. For example, if one knows the length of rectangle A, one knows the length of rectangle B, because the figure description says rectangle A and B are identical. And if one knows the diamater of semicircle C , one also knows the width of rectangle A and B.Finally, the diameter of semicircle C is related to its area by Area = pi* (D/2)^2

Hence, I would like to implement a algorithm such that, the moment one of the linked variables (e.g area,length, diamater, radius) is changed, the remaining linked variables also change appropriately.

What in your opinion is the best way to implement this? Could I use, for example, recursion to update through all linked variables, or getter and setter properties, for example?

I use python as my preferred language.
Thanks.

[image: A figure where the measurements are linked]

Comment: You can first implement the behavior of two primitives within own classes, then combine the primitives with a constructor function, that returns new shapes. The code you tried is welcome in the question.

Comment: You will need some abstract variable concept, where variables can either be user input or calculated values. For the calculated values, a publisher/subscriber design sounds reasonable. However, figuring out the equations and their solution can become very tricky. Especially when you get equations that do not have analytical solutions. Or no solution at all. Check out how [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/) is doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can formulate this as a constraint satisfaction problem

```
CA = 20
CA = Cr^2 * Pi/2
Ba = Aa
Bb = Ab
Aa = 3
Ab = 2 * Cr
```

and solve it with [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3), which has a python interface (see e.g. this [intro](https://yurichev.com/writings/SAT_SMT_draft-EN.pdf)):

```
from z3 import *

CA, Cr, Ba, Bb, Aa, Ab = [Real(v) for v in ["CA", "Cr", "Ba", "Bb", "Aa", "Ab"]]
E1 = CA == 20
E2 = CA == Cr*Cr * 3.14159/2
E3 = Ba == Aa
E4 = Bb == Ab
E5 = Aa == 3
E6 = Ab == 2 * Cr
C1 = Cr > 0

s = Solver()
s.add(E1, E2, E3, E4, E5, E6, C1)
if str(s.check()) == 'sat':
  print(s.model())
else:
  print("not solvable")
```

output:

```
[Cr = 3.5682497392?,
 Aa = 3,
 Bb = 7.1364994785?,
 Ab = 7.1364994785?,
 Ba = 3,
 CA = 20]
```